# why setting dtype on numpy array changes dimensions?

Tags: python, numpy

I am tryng to understand how to set dtypes of an array. My original numpy array dimensions are (583760, 7) i.e. 583760 rows and 7 columns. I am setting dtype as follows

```
>>> allRics.shape
(583760, 7)
>>> allRics.dtype = [('idx', np.float), ('opened', np.float), ('time', np.float),('trdp1',np.float),('trdp0',np.float),('dt',np.float),('value',np.float)]
>>> allRics.shape
(583760, 1)
```

Why is there a change in the original shape of the array? What causes this change? I am basically trying to sort original numpy array by `time` column and thats why I am setting the `dtype`. But after the dimension change, I am not able to sort array

```
>>> x=np.sort(allRics,order='time')
```

there is no change in the output of the above command. Could you please advice?

Comment: What do you expect to see happen instead of that?

Comment: the dimensions should remain same `(583760,7)` and finally I should be able to sort using `order='time'` column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are turning your array into a [structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html).  Basically, instead of a 2D array it is now treated as a 1D array of structs.  Take a look as a simpler example below:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([(1,2,3),(3,4,5)])
>>> arr
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [3, 4, 5]])
>>> arr.shape
(2, 3)
>>> arr.dtype=[('a',int),('b',int),('c', int)]
>>> arr  # Notice that tuples inside the elements
array([[(1, 2, 3)],
       [(3, 4, 5)]], 
      dtype=[('a', '<i8'), ('b', '<i8'), ('c', '<i8')])
>>> arr.shape
(2, 1)
```

The structured array not sorting is most assurdly a [bug](http://www.mail-archive.com/numpy-discussion@scipy.org/msg23060.html).  It looks like a work around it so actually declare the array a structured array to begin with:

```
>>> arr_s = np.sort(arr, order='b')
>>> arr_s
array([[(1, 2, 3)],
       [(3, 4, 5)]], 
      dtype=[('a', '<i8'), ('b', '<i8'), ('c', '<i8')])
>>> dtype=[('a',np.int64),('b',np.int64),('c', np.int64)]
>>> arr = np.array([(5,2,3),(3,4,1)], dtype=dtype)
>>> arr
array([(5, 2, 3), (3, 4, 1)], 
      dtype=[('a', '<i8'), ('b', '<i8'), ('c', '<i8')])
>>> arr_s = np.sort(arr, order='a')
>>> arr_s
array([(3, 4, 1), (5, 2, 3)], 
      dtype=[('a', '<i8'), ('b', '<i8'), ('c', '<i8')])
>>> arr_s = np.sort(arr, order='b')
>>> arr_s
array([(5, 2, 3), (3, 4, 1)], 
      dtype=[('a', '<i8'), ('b', '<i8'), ('c', '<i8')])
>>> arr_s = np.sort(arr, order='c')
>>> arr_s
array([(3, 4, 1), (5, 2, 3)], 
      dtype=[('a', '<i8'), ('b', '<i8'), ('c', '<i8')])
>>>
```

Comment: did you mean `now` instead of `not` ?

Comment: So that explains my output array. it seems to be correct. I don't understand why my sort function doesn't work. `x=np.sort(allRics,order='time')` is not sorted by `time` column. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Yes `now` not `not`, also added comments on the sorting.  Looks to be a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I guess the issue is with the endianness of the columns which maybe causing the problem. I will try it out.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to avoid using structured arrays alltogether if all you are using them for is sorting. You could do something like:

```
new_order = np.argosrt(allRics[:, 2])
x = allRics[new_order]
```

Comment: Thanks. I already implemented the same solution. it worked for me.